# Исчезает Design при добавлении TabLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, xml

При добавлении TabLayout пропадает весь Design и TabLayout не отображается в Component Tree

[image]

Причем в коде он появляется, но с ошибкой

[image]

Comment: делать что-то опираясь только на дизайн такая себе затея, он не всегда отображает актуальную ситуацию, я бы советовал писать только через текстовый xml, там есть опция split по-моему чтобы можно было и разметку в тексте видеть и дизайн, а таб бар с ошибкой потому что наверное вы это все делаете в ConstraintLayout и вы не добавили привязки к виджету

Comment: Добавьте текст ошибки в вопрос, без этого ваш вопрос не найти в поиске, и он будет полезен другим пользователям.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена после обновления Android Studio